# Executing code after router.navigate in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wonder if there is a way to execute something after i navigate to a different "view" using angular router.

```
this.router.navigate(["/search", "1", ""]);
// Everything after navigate does not not get executed.
this.sideFiltersService.discoverFilter(category);
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

this.router.navigate returns a promise so you can simply use:

```js
this.router.navigate(["/search", "1", ""]).then(()=>{
  // do whatever you need after navigation succeeds
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this promise globally?

Answer (score 3):

```js
// In javascript
this.router.navigate(["/search", "1", ""])
    .then(succeeded => {
        if(succeeded)
        {
            // Do your stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // Do some other stuff
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle the error
    });
```

```
// In typescript you can use the javascript example as well.
// But you can also do:
try
{
    let succeeded = await this.router.navigate(["/search", "1", ""]);
    if(succeeded)
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some other stuff
    }
}
catch(error)
{
    // Handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure of the context but an option would be to subscribe to a change in the URL using `ActivatedRoute`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#activated-route

Here's an example:

```
...
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

private _routerSubscription: any;

// Some class or service

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute){
    this._routerSubscription = this._route.url.subscribe(url => {
        // Your action/function will go here
    });
}
```

There are many other observables you can subscribe to in `ActivatedRoute` which are listed in that link if url isn't quite what you need.

The subscription can be done in the `constructor()` or in an `ngOnInit()` depending on what suits you best, just remember to clean up after yourself and unsubscribe in an `ngOnDestroy()` :)

```
this._routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are navigated from `ComponentA` to `ComponentB` then after navigating you can do any actions in `ngOnInit()` function of `ComponentB`, depending upon the parameters passed in the route.

Comment: I don't have any param in the URL that differentiate between the route called normally or through this method

Comment: Then try doing with a shared service, set any flag in service from ComponentA and navigate then check this flag in ngOnInit() of ComponentB and perform your desired actions.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to ensure that there are no ongoing subscriptions... I faced the same problem and in my case there was a subscription which changed route. So the route has been changed twice. But practically you can use promises, thats right